# Is adding a sleep to my code to be able to show a loading icon effective for informing the user

Tags: icons, response-time, loading

I have follow / un follow feature on my website.

Currently, you click the button and using PHP and AJAX I change the button background colour.

This is a simple action for the website so doesn't take long and normally it changes instantly.

Just incase, i do have a loading spinner appear over the button when its processing but you dont get a change to see this because of the speed it happens.

I have been playing around with a PHP function called sleep().

When you put e.g. sleep(1); inside your code it will stop the page running for a second before continuing.

I am liking how this feels for the user.

They click the button and can see that something is happening because of there action and then a second later the button changes its colour.

Its only a short 1 second delay. But i am just looking for some other opinions whether this would be effective in aiding the user to see what is going on. Or should it just be instantaneous?

Thanks!

Comment: I wouldn't do it, for the same reasons as I wouldn't add an artificial load delay: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/41682/pros-cons-of-splash-screen-with-articifial-loading-delay/41695#41695

Comment: I understand your reasoning, but personally i feel you're deliberately crippling the UX by forcing loading times, but that's a matter of personal opinion. Using sleep() to do so is very bad practice. Instead, use Javascript to make the AJAX call a second after the button is clicked.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The option that you have chosen is an elegant solution. You can further spice it up by adding additional emotional element along with loading spinner saying "He/She will miss you" (Rephrase the text depending upon the width). You can get several other button progress samples from [this website](http://tympanus.net/Development/ProgressButtonStyles/)

Comment: Thanks for the link! Some amazing samples on that site not just on the button progress. Shall look at implementing some!