# The ideal Splash Screen for mobile applications should be animated or static?

Tags: mobile, mobile-application, splash-screen

The manager asks for animated Splash screen, but I am against it, since the animation can slow down and annoy the user, but what do you think?

Comment: What's the splash page for? If it's a placeholder that's shown while a view is being prepared, then an animation is not necessarily detrimental to load time. I'd say this becomes more of an issue the shorter the real load time is, because you ideally don't want to impact load performance any more than you need to. But maybe you're primarily showing it as part of the app branding. In which case some page load time may be traded off to help build brand engagement. If you provide more details, we'll be able to answer more specifically.

Comment: People tend to make requests without including background knowledge and values supporting their request. But for another to best meet the request it helps for all to explore the underlying principles and purpose. Asking requesters what are the principles/values motivating their request helps them either reveal the justification or reconsider their, possibly misguided, request.

Comment: This may help: [Pros/cons of splash-screen with articifial loading delay](https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/41682/93969)

Comment: Is there any app load time that can be used for a splash screen? If branding is the purpose, is there sufficient, appropriate branding in the app interface itself?

Answer (score 1):

When in doubt, do user testing! Prepare both versions, at least in mock up, and let the users run through it multiple times. Since part of the concern is that users will be annoyed having to watch the animation every time the app loads, you can give them multiple tasks and ask them to exit the app in between. If the users are annoyed, then you have data to show your manager. And if the users don't mind or like the animation, then you've learned something.

As others have pointed out in the comments, a lot depends on when the app would look like without the animation. A simple animation may not actually have a noticeable affect on load time, and if the app needs to load a lot of data for core functions, *the animation can actually give a cue that something is going on in the background*. If the animation takes longer than the load time of essential functions, then you're wasting the user's time for no tangible benefit.